# Instalação bloqueada ao depurar app pelo Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-permission

Ao tentar depurar ou instalar um aplicativo que estou desenvolvendo, é exibida a seguinte mensagem no aparelho onde a APK está sendo instalada.

**Instalação bloqueada.**

**Esse app contém um código criado com a intenção de burlar as proteções de segurança do Android.**

Isso começou a acontecer do nada, tive que excluir o projeto e fazer checkout novamente pelo SVN, e refazer o que tinha alterado, funcionou no primeiro momento, mas agora após qualquer alteração no código, esse erro volta a aparecer.

Este projeto já é bem grande, pouco mais de um ano de desenvolvimento.

Não encontrei nenhum caso parecido na internet, espero que alguém possa me ajudar com isso.

**Permissões utilizadas pelo app:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<permission
    android:name="br.com.empresa.projeto.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="br.com.empresa.projeto.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.empresa.projeto"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.6"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile files('libs/androidasync-2.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/ion-2.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/generalscan_sdk.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile files('libs/core-3.2.0.jar')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**Um detalhe interessante, isso começou pouco depois de integrar o Android Studio ao SVN, antes usava a ferramenta TortoiseSVN.**

Comment: a versão do android no aparelho é 23 ou maior?

Comment: não, é a 21, mas uso algumas bibliotecas do 23.
o próprio google cria projetos dessa forma.

Comment: Caso não ache uma solução, não deixe de reportar o problema para a equipe de desenvolvimento do android. Pode não parecer, mas ajuda muito, passei por problemas e enviei um feedback muito detalhado, já na versão seguinte, tinham resolvido, não sei se é o caso, mas fica a dica.

Comment: Value pela dica, vou fazer isso, o problema estava na apk gerada apartir de uma já existente, para resolver simplesmente deletava a apk antes de compilar novamente para que fosse criada uma nova.
Porem esse erro não me ocorre mais, talvez já tenham corrigido isso.

Comment: Vá removendo as permissões do seu manifest e tente detectar se é alguma delas que causa o erro. Depois tente fazer isso com o gradle. Vá por partes até descobrir o causador.

Answer (score 1):

Creio que além de habilitar a depuração USB, tu deverá habilitar a opção: Fontes desconhecidas, acessando o Menu configurações e indo em Segurança no seu device.

Comment: Essa seria a minha última alternativa, ele é usado apenas pela empresa e temos 60 aparelhos rodando esse app, fica meio inviável fazer isso em todos, até porque alguns nem no Brasil estão.
O estranho é que isso nunca tinha acontecido, e do nada isso começou a acontecer.

Answer (score 0):

Fala Heris,

Olhando seu código, acredito que o que está bloqueando é isso aqui:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
```

Qual a função dele? Você tentou tirar e compilar?

E eu reparei também, que você está colocando os **.jar** das libs, tenta colocar o link do gradle, por exemplo:

ao invés de:

```
compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
```

tenta colocar:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Abraços.

Comment: Já havia retirado essa permissão e mesmo assim não funcionou, tentei também trocar para o link do gradle como você disse mas também não funcionou.